# Nginx: how can I redirect `www.mydomain.com` to `www.mydomain.com/something`

Tags: django, nginx

With Nginx, how can I redirect `www.mydomain.com` to `www.mydomain.com/something` ?

I have tried by changing from this:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
        # ...
}
```

to this:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/something;
        # ...
}
```

And yes, when I visit `www.mydomain.com`, I'm automatically reidrected to `www.mydomain.com/something`, but then many links fail. By the way, we are talking about a `Django` app.

I would just want to be redirected to `www.mydomain.com/something` the first time I visit `www.mydomain.com`

Comment: Are you saying you want to be redirected only the first time, and subsequent visits should keep you at `/` ?

Comment: You just want to redirect your example.com/ to example.com/something? without changing the structure of the urls?

Comment: @karthikr: Subsequent visits should take me to wherever  the application needs to go. It may be `pageA`, `pageB`, etc...

Comment: @TomaszKajtoch: Yes, that is exactly what I would like to do.

Comment: When you say many links fail... are you using the `url` template tag throughout your application? do you have examples of urls that are now failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do it:

1. The first one is to redirect from / to any location you want on django level:

   **myproject/urls.py**

   ```
   from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

   urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/something', permanent=True), name='index')
       [...]
   ]
   ```
2. Another way is to redirect the traffic on nginx level using [rewrite](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) module. For me it's less convenient - if you decide to change the path or whatever else you must modify your nginx configuration.

   **conf.d/mydomain.conf**

   ```
   server {
       [...]
       location / {
           rewrite ^/$ /something permanent;
           [...]
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you @Thomasz Katjoch. I chose your first alternative and it is just what I needed.